# How to convert svg to png and center text with PHP?

Tags: php, imagick

I try to convert svg to png with PHP and imagick. The svg code in this example is this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="128" height="128">
    <path fill="#dc76e9" d="M0 0h16v16H0z"/>
    <text x="8" y="8" fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" dy=".3em" font-family="Arial" font-size="7">RO</text>
</svg>
```

The result should look like this image:

[image: desired result]

But currently it looks like this:

[image: current result]

I would like to center the text vertically. The font family is currently not important for me.

This is my code for the conversion:

```
<?php
$svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="128" height="128">
            <path fill="#dc76e9" d="M0 0h16v16H0z"/>
            <text x="8" y="8" fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" dy=".3em" font-family="Arial" font-size="7">RO</text>
        </svg>';

$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImageBlob($svg);
$im->setImageBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));

$im->setImageFormat("png24");
$im->resizeImage(128, 128, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1, true);
$im->writeImage("image.png");
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like ImageMagick is using its own internal, limited, MSVG rendering engine. It'll get the job done, but it doesn't understand most "web-based" instructions that we expect from a browser. In this case, the `em` part of `dy=".3em"`.

Two solutions I can think of...

- Install [RSVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Librsvg), and update ImageMagick's delegates
- Remove the `em` and manually update the SVG.

```xml
<text x="8" y="8" fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" dy="1.3" font-family="Arial" font-size="7">RO</text>
                                              <!-- ^^^^^^^^ -->
```

Comment: Also could use Inkscape, which is often better than RSVG.